# org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, server, xalan

I am getting the below error while trying to deploy my application on a Apache Tomcat server. I am using Apache Tomcat 8.0.32 and JDK 1.8.0_131.

```
SEVERE: Servlet [portalsim] in web application [/portalsim] threw load() exception
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory: Provider org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Show us your maven and Xalan version?

Comment: java.version=1.8.0_131
version.xalan2_2=Xalan Java 2.7.0
Apache Maven 3.0.4